# Unique after filter Angular

Tags: angularjs, filter

So I've been trying to figure this out for a while but it's still stumping me.

Ultimately I want to be able to do the following

```
    object in objects | unique:'DateTime | limitTo:4'//As the year is the first 4 characters
```

(oh well y10k :))

But I don't know how I'd write that, I'd prefer to have it be inline html code so I don't need to mess around with dependency injection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the `unique` filter from angular-ui?

Comment: I was, but I wasn't able to get it to actually filter AND go through unique, I've been trying to get both unique and limitTo to function properly

Comment: Are you trying to repeat through objects having distinct years? Or are you also filtering based on some user input? (i.e. using the [filter filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter))

Comment: To clarify,
Collection> Object> Property> limitTo(or Date:'yyyy')> Unique
Is what I was going for

Comment: Understood. I suggest writing your own implementation of `unique` which (unlike the angular-ui `unique`) can take a string key or a key function as an argument. Then you will have `object in objects | unique:extractYear` where `extractYear` is a function that takes an object, and returns the year part of its `DateTime`.

Comment: I know I could do that, but I was really hoping for a clean and simple html snippit

Comment: I'm afraid what you want isn't possible with built-in or angular-ui filters, in part because the `unique` filter cannot accept an expression or a function in place of a key.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this derictive:**

```
.filter('unique', function () {
    return function (items, filterOn) {
        if (filterOn === false) {
            return items;
        }
        if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
            var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];
            var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
                if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
                    return item[filterOn];
                } else {
                    return item;
                }
            };
            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
                    if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
                        isDuplicate = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isDuplicate) {
                    newItems.push(item);
                }
            });
            items = newItems;
        }
        return items;
    };
});
```